# Get subcategory and subsubcategory and infinite subsubsubcategory

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchical-data

I'm trying to loop a function that takes all subcategorys.. from one main category into one table and put in array.

Example table:

```
ID   | ParentID
1    | 0
2    | 1
3    | 1
4    | 2
5    | 4
6    | 3
7    | 1
```

(Subcategories have parentID)

Now the example in function PHP taking all subsubcategories of a main category (ID=1)

```
    var_dump(getSubCategories(1));

    function getSubCategories($parent_id = 0, $subcategories = array())
    {
        global $db;

        $query = $db->query("
SELECT ID 
  FROM categories
 WHERE ParentID = $parent_id 
 ORDER 
    BY Name ASC
");

        while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
            $subcategories = getSubCategories($row['ID'], $subcategories);
        }
        return $subcategories;
    }
```

The problem is to put the IDs inside an array, because the code above prints this result:

```
array(0) { }
```

One thing I noticed is that if I add this line below while:

```
echo $row['ID'] . ',';
```

It prints the result correctly, but not as an array:

```
2,3,4,5,6,7
```

My expectation was like this for example: `array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)` etc.. without being multidimensional.

Comment: You can do this directly in your query. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query

Comment: I also answered a similar question some time ago. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/192462#192462

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you keep overwriting `$subcategories` instead of adding to it. Also, you need to add the current `$row['ID']` value to the array. You need to change this line:

```
$subcategories = getSubCategories($row['ID'], $subcategories);
```

to

```
$subcategories = array_merge($subcategories, array($row['ID']), getSubCategories($row['ID']);
```

Comment: Adding $subcategories[] = $row['ID']; inside while and before array_merge works perfectly, thanks.

Comment: @Slinidy oops! I meant to add a third parameter to the `array_merge` which was that. See my edit to do it in one line.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass `$subcategories` parameter [by reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

```
    $subCategories = array();
    getSubCategories(1, $subCategories);
    var_dump($subCategories);
    function getSubCategories(&$subCategories, $parent_id = 0)
    {
        global $db;

        $query = $db->query("
SELECT ID 
  FROM categories
 WHERE ParentID = $parent_id 
 ORDER 
    BY Name ASC
");
        while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
            getSubCategories($subCategories, $row['ID']);
        }
    }
```

Or just append the results to `$subcategories` variable.

```
    var_dump(getSubCategories(1));
    function getSubCategories($parent_id = 0)
    {
        global $db;

        $query = $db->query("
SELECT ID 
  FROM categories
 WHERE ParentID = $parent_id 
 ORDER 
    BY Name ASC
");
        $subcategories = array();
        while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
            $subcategories = array_merge($subcategories, getSubCategories($row['ID']));
        }
        return $subcategories;
    }
```